# System UI keeps stopping error on lock screen

Tags: android, system, rom

System UI keeps stopping in the lock screen. the screen turns black on its own available actions sound profiles and power menu. I can’t look at the log, I don’t know where to look at the system log in order to know what caused this error when using the phone, the error occurs but corrects itself. Help me please! I want to know and correct or prevent the cause of the error! I use A10 EvoX 4.7 fans_edition KMaQ.

tried to disable services, activities from system ui with MyAndroidTools zero effect. I cleared the app's cache to no avail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.